# MVC - DropDownList value changed after POST command on different form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View, Index, that has two forms, a search form and a save form. They both have DropDownList controls bound to the same Application data source, but that is the only thing they have in common.

When I save the data using a POST request, the DDL in the search form changes to become the same value as the one in the save form, which is not an action that I want. Here is my stripped-down code:

```
@model Models.InfoVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "MyController")) {
    @Html.DropDownList("searchCodes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Application["Codes"], "--Select--")
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController")) {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Application["Codes"], Model != null ? Model.Code : "--Select--")
}
```

And my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]InfoVM model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        Repository.UpdateInfo(model);
    }
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I break this link between the two? Since I have not bound the search form's DDL to the Model I have bound to the page, I did not expect the value to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If the value of the model changes, it changes for all the elements on the page.

You should have different model properties for the drop down in two forms. You can copy the elements (and not just reference the same) into a different variable. E.g. Try creating CodesForSearch and CodesForSave. Populate both these SelectLists using the same source. Bind the drop downs with their own separate variable.

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't aware that was the expected behavior.